# ActionView::Template::Error: wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 1) updating to Ruby 3.1.2 and Rails 7

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-5, ruby-on-rails-7

I'm trying to update from Ruby 2.7.6 to 3.1.2. I'm hung up with a 500 error. Can anyone tell me how to fix it?

This is the error stuff from the run config:

```
Processing by HomeController#index as HTML
  Rendering layout layouts/application.html.erb
  Rendering home/index.html.erb within layouts/application
  Rendered home/index.html.erb within layouts/application (Duration: 1.5ms | Allocations: 398)
  Rendered layout layouts/application.html.erb (Duration: 29.8ms | Allocations: 5518)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 45ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms | Allocations: 9550)


  
ActionView::Template::Error (wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 1)):
     5:     <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge,chrome=1">
     6:     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
     7:     <title><%= content_for?(:title) ? yield(:title) : "Workspace" %></title>
     8:     <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
     9: 
    10:     <%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", :media => "all" %>
    11: 
  
app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:8
```

Here is my gemfile (updated):

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'


# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
#gem 'rails', '5.0.7.2'
gem 'rails', '~> 7.0.0'
#ruby "2.6.4"
#ruby '2.7.6'
#ruby '3.0.4'
ruby '3.1.2'


# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
gem 'devise'
gem 'twitter-bootstrap-rails'
gem 'devise-bootstrap-views'
gem 'bootstrap-datepicker-rails'
# Use Puma as the app server
gem 'puma'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
#gem 'sass-rails'
gem 'sassc'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails'
gem 'carrierwave', '1.3.1'
gem 'mini_magick', '4.9.3'
gem 'fog-aws'
#gem 'ransack', '2.1.1'
gem 'ransack', '~> 3.2', '>= 3.2.1'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'jquery-ui-rails'
# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
#gem 'turbolinks'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc

#gem 'bundler', '~> 1.17', '>= 1.17.2'

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

gem 'sendgrid-ruby'

#gem 'pg', '~> 0.18'
gem 'pg', '~> 1.4', '>= 1.4.2'

#gem 'sprockets-rails', '~> 3.0', '>= 3.0.4'
gem 'sprockets-rails', :require => 'sprockets/railtie'

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  #gem 'sqlite3', '~> 1.3.6'
  gem 'byebug'
end

group :development do
  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> in views
  #gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'
  gem 'web-console', '~> 4.2'

  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
end

group :production do
  #gem 'pg'
  #changing this to see if I can fix the heroku error
  #gem 'pg', '~> 0.18'
  gem 'rails_12factor'
end
```

and here is my gemfile.lock (updated)

```
GEM
  remote: https://rubygems.org/
  specs:
    actioncable (7.0.4)
      actionpack (= 7.0.4)
      activesupport (= 7.0.4)
      nio4r (~> 2.0)
      websocket-driver (>= 0.6.1)
    actionmailbox (7.0.4)
      actionpack (= 7.0.4)
      activejob (= 7.0.4)
      activerecord (= 7.0.4)
      activestorage (= 7.0.4)
      activesupport (= 7.0.4)
      mail (>= 2.7.1)
      net-imap
      net-pop
      net-smtp
    actionmailer (7.0.4)
      actionpack (= 7.0.4)
      actionview (= 7.0.4)
      activejob (= 7.0.4)
      activesupport (= 7.0.4)
      mail (~> 2.5, >= 2.5.4)
      net-imap
      net-pop
      net-smtp
      rails-dom-testing (~> 2.0)
    actionpack (7.0.4)
      actionview (= 7.0.4)
      activesupport (= 7.0.4)
      rack (~> 2.0, >= 2.2.0)
      rack-test (>= 0.6.3)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 2.0)
      rails-html-sanitizer (~> 1.0, >= 1.2.0)
    actiontext (7.0.4)
      actionpack (= 7.0.4)
      activerecord (= 7.0.4)
      activestorage (= 7.0.4)
      activesupport (= 7.0.4)
      globalid (>= 0.6.0)
      nokogiri (>= 1.8.5)
    actionview (7.0.4)
      activesupport (= 7.0.4)
      builder (~> 3.1)
      erubi (~> 1.4)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 2.0)
      rails-html-sanitizer (~> 1.1, >= 1.2.0)
    activejob (7.0.4)
      activesupport (= 7.0.4)
      globalid (>= 0.3.6)
    activemodel (7.0.4)
      activesupport (= 7.0.4)
    activerecord (7.0.4)
      activemodel (= 7.0.4)
      activesupport (= 7.0.4)
    activestorage (7.0.4)
      actionpack (= 7.0.4)
      activejob (= 7.0.4)
      activerecord (= 7.0.4)
      activesupport (= 7.0.4)
      marcel (~> 1.0)
      mini_mime (>= 1.1.0)
    activesupport (7.0.4)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.2)
      i18n (>= 1.6, < 2)
      minitest (>= 5.1)
      tzinfo (~> 2.0)
    bcrypt (3.1.18)
    bindex (0.8.1)
    bootstrap-datepicker-rails (1.9.0.1)
      railties (>= 3.0)
    builder (3.2.4)
    byebug (11.1.3)
    carrierwave (1.3.1)
      activemodel (>= 4.0.0)
      activesupport (>= 4.0.0)
      mime-types (>= 1.16)
    coffee-rails (5.0.0)
      coffee-script (>= 2.2.0)
      railties (>= 5.2.0)
    coffee-script (2.4.1)
      coffee-script-source
      execjs
    coffee-script-source (1.12.2)
    commonjs (0.2.7)
    concurrent-ruby (1.1.10)
    crass (1.0.6)
    devise (4.8.1)
      bcrypt (~> 3.0)
      orm_adapter (~> 0.1)
      railties (>= 4.1.0)
      responders
      warden (~> 1.2.3)
    devise-bootstrap-views (1.1.0)
    erubi (1.11.0)
    excon (0.94.0)
    execjs (2.8.1)
    ffi (1.15.5)
    fog-aws (3.15.0)
      fog-core (~> 2.1)
      fog-json (~> 1.1)
      fog-xml (~> 0.1)
    fog-core (2.3.0)
      builder
      excon (~> 0.71)
      formatador (>= 0.2, < 2.0)
      mime-types
    fog-json (1.2.0)
      fog-core
      multi_json (~> 1.10)
    fog-xml (0.1.4)
      fog-core
      nokogiri (>= 1.5.11, < 2.0.0)
    formatador (1.1.0)
    globalid (1.0.0)
      activesupport (>= 5.0)
    i18n (1.12.0)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0)
    jbuilder (2.11.5)
      actionview (>= 5.0.0)
      activesupport (>= 5.0.0)
    jquery-rails (4.5.1)
      rails-dom-testing (>= 1, < 3)
      railties (>= 4.2.0)
      thor (>= 0.14, < 2.0)
    jquery-ui-rails (6.0.1)
      railties (>= 3.2.16)
    json (1.8.6)
    less (2.6.0)
      commonjs (~> 0.2.7)
    less-rails (4.0.0)
      actionpack (>= 4)
      less (~> 2.6.0)
      sprockets (>= 2)
    loofah (2.19.0)
      crass (~> 1.0.2)
      nokogiri (>= 1.5.9)
    mail (2.8.0)
      mini_mime (>= 0.1.1)
      net-imap
      net-pop
      net-smtp
    marcel (1.0.2)
    method_source (1.0.0)
    mime-types (3.4.1)
      mime-types-data (~> 3.2015)
    mime-types-data (3.2022.0105)
    mini_magick (4.9.3)
    mini_mime (1.1.2)
    mini_portile2 (2.8.0)
    minitest (5.16.3)
    multi_json (1.15.0)
    net-imap (0.3.1)
      net-protocol
    net-pop (0.1.2)
      net-protocol
    net-protocol (0.2.0)
      timeout
    net-smtp (0.3.3)
      net-protocol
    nio4r (2.5.8)
    nokogiri (1.13.10)
      mini_portile2 (~> 2.8.0)
      racc (~> 1.4)
    orm_adapter (0.5.0)
    pg (1.4.5)
    puma (6.0.0)
      nio4r (~> 2.0)
    racc (1.6.1)
    rack (2.2.4)
    rack-test (2.0.2)
      rack (>= 1.3)
    rails (7.0.4)
      actioncable (= 7.0.4)
      actionmailbox (= 7.0.4)
      actionmailer (= 7.0.4)
      actionpack (= 7.0.4)
      actiontext (= 7.0.4)
      actionview (= 7.0.4)
      activejob (= 7.0.4)
      activemodel (= 7.0.4)
      activerecord (= 7.0.4)
      activestorage (= 7.0.4)
      activesupport (= 7.0.4)
      bundler (>= 1.15.0)
      railties (= 7.0.4)
    rails-dom-testing (2.0.3)
      activesupport (>= 4.2.0)
      nokogiri (>= 1.6)
    rails-html-sanitizer (1.4.3)
      loofah (~> 2.3)
    rails_12factor (0.0.3)
      rails_serve_static_assets
      rails_stdout_logging
    rails_serve_static_assets (0.0.5)
    rails_stdout_logging (0.0.5)
    railties (7.0.4)
      actionpack (= 7.0.4)
      activesupport (= 7.0.4)
      method_source
      rake (>= 12.2)
      thor (~> 1.0)
      zeitwerk (~> 2.5)
    rake (13.0.6)
    ransack (3.2.1)
      activerecord (>= 6.1.5)
      activesupport (>= 6.1.5)
      i18n
    rdoc (4.3.0)
    responders (3.0.1)
      actionpack (>= 5.0)
      railties (>= 5.0)
    ruby_http_client (3.5.5)
    sassc (2.4.0)
      ffi (~> 1.9)
    sdoc (0.4.2)
      json (~> 1.7, >= 1.7.7)
      rdoc (~> 4.0)
    sendgrid-ruby (6.6.2)
      ruby_http_client (~> 3.4)
    spring (4.1.0)
    sprockets (4.1.1)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0)
      rack (> 1, < 3)
    sprockets-rails (3.4.2)
      actionpack (>= 5.2)
      activesupport (>= 5.2)
      sprockets (>= 3.0.0)
    thor (1.2.1)
    timeout (0.3.1)
    twitter-bootstrap-rails (5.0.0)
      actionpack (>= 5.0, < 8.0)
      execjs (~> 2.7)
      less-rails (>= 3.0, < 5.0)
      railties (>= 5.0, < 8.0)
    tzinfo (2.0.5)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0)
    uglifier (4.2.0)
      execjs (>= 0.3.0, < 3)
    warden (1.2.9)
      rack (>= 2.0.9)
    web-console (4.2.0)
      actionview (>= 6.0.0)
      activemodel (>= 6.0.0)
      bindex (>= 0.4.0)
      railties (>= 6.0.0)
    websocket-driver (0.7.5)
      websocket-extensions (>= 0.1.0)
    websocket-extensions (0.1.5)
    zeitwerk (2.6.6)

PLATFORMS
  ruby

DEPENDENCIES
  bootstrap-datepicker-rails
  byebug
  carrierwave (= 1.3.1)
  coffee-rails
  devise
  devise-bootstrap-views
  fog-aws
  jbuilder
  jquery-rails
  jquery-ui-rails
  mini_magick (= 4.9.3)
  pg (~> 1.4, >= 1.4.2)
  puma
  rails (~> 7.0.0)
  rails_12factor
  ransack (~> 3.2, >= 3.2.1)
  sassc
  sdoc (~> 0.4.0)
  sendgrid-ruby
  spring
  sprockets-rails
  twitter-bootstrap-rails
  uglifier (>= 1.3.0)
  web-console (~> 4.2)

RUBY VERSION
   ruby 3.1.2p20

BUNDLED WITH
   2.3.7
```

And here is the full trace from the error page - does that maybe help?

```
json (1.8.6) lib/json/common.rb:155:in `initialize'
json (1.8.6) lib/json/common.rb:155:in `new'
json (1.8.6) lib/json/common.rb:155:in `parse'
sprockets (4.1.1) lib/sprockets/sassc_processor.rb:63:in `call'
sprockets (4.1.1) lib/sprockets/sassc_processor.rb:31:in `call'
sprockets (4.1.1) lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:84:in `call_processor'
sprockets (4.1.1) lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:66:in `block in call_processors'
sprockets (4.1.1) lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:65:in `reverse_each'
sprockets (4.1.1) lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:65:in `call_processors'
sprockets (4.1.1) lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:22:in `block in <class:CompositeProcessor>'
sprockets (4.1.1) lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:33:in `call'
sprockets (4.1.1) lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:84:in `call_processor'
sprockets (4.1.1) lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:66:in `block in call_processors'
sprockets (4.1.1) lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:65:in `reverse_each'
sprockets (4.1.1) lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:65:in `call_processors'
sprockets (4.1.1) lib/sprockets/loader.rb:182:in `load_from_unloaded'
sprockets (4.1.1) lib/sprockets/loader.rb:59:in `block in load'
sprockets (4.1.1) lib/sprockets/loader.rb:337:in `fetch_asset_from_dependency_cache'
sprockets (4.1.1) lib/sprockets/loader.rb:43:in `load'
sprockets (4.1.1) lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:44:in `block in load'
sprockets (4.1.1) lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:44:in `fetch'
sprockets (4.1.1) lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:44:in `load'
sprockets (4.1.1) lib/sprockets/bundle.rb:41:in `block in call'
sprockets (4.1.1) lib/sprockets/utils.rb:170:in `dfs'
sprockets (4.1.1) lib/sprockets/bundle.rb:42:in `call'
sprockets (4.1.1) lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:84:in `call_processor'
sprockets (4.1.1) lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:66:in `block in call_processors'
sprockets (4.1.1) lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:65:in `reverse_each'
sprockets (4.1.1) lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:65:in `call_processors'
sprockets (4.1.1) lib/sprockets/loader.rb:182:in `load_from_unloaded'
sprockets (4.1.1) lib/sprockets/loader.rb:59:in `block in load'
sprockets (4.1.1) lib/sprockets/loader.rb:337:in `fetch_asset_from_dependency_cache'
sprockets (4.1.1) lib/sprockets/loader.rb:43:in `load'
sprockets (4.1.1) lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:44:in `block in load'
sprockets (4.1.1) lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:44:in `fetch'
sprockets (4.1.1) lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:44:in `load'
sprockets (4.1.1) lib/sprockets/add_source_map_comment_to_asset_processor.rb:45:in `call'
sprockets (4.1.1) lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:84:in `call_processor'
sprockets (4.1.1) lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:66:in `block in call_processors'
sprockets (4.1.1) lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:65:in `reverse_each'
sprockets (4.1.1) lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:65:in `call_processors'
sprockets (4.1.1) lib/sprockets/loader.rb:182:in `load_from_unloaded'
sprockets (4.1.1) lib/sprockets/loader.rb:59:in `block in load'
sprockets (4.1.1) lib/sprockets/loader.rb:337:in `fetch_asset_from_dependency_cache'
sprockets (4.1.1) lib/sprockets/loader.rb:43:in `load'
sprockets (4.1.1) lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:44:in `block in load'
sprockets (4.1.1) lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:44:in `fetch'
sprockets (4.1.1) lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:44:in `load'
sprockets (4.1.1) lib/sprockets/base.rb:81:in `find_asset'
sprockets (4.1.1) lib/sprockets/base.rb:119:in `[]'
sprockets-rails (3.4.2) lib/sprockets/rails/helper.rb:358:in `find_asset'
sprockets-rails (3.4.2) lib/sprockets/rails/helper.rb:348:in `find_debug_asset'
sprockets-rails (3.4.2) lib/sprockets/rails/helper.rb:230:in `block in lookup_debug_asset'
sprockets-rails (3.4.2) lib/sprockets/rails/helper.rb:243:in `block in resolve_asset'
sprockets-rails (3.4.2) lib/sprockets/rails/helper.rb:242:in `each'
sprockets-rails (3.4.2) lib/sprockets/rails/helper.rb:242:in `detect'
sprockets-rails (3.4.2) lib/sprockets/rails/helper.rb:242:in `resolve_asset'
sprockets-rails (3.4.2) lib/sprockets/rails/helper.rb:229:in `lookup_debug_asset'
sprockets-rails (3.4.2) lib/sprockets/rails/helper.rb:171:in `block in stylesheet_link_tag'
sprockets-rails (3.4.2) lib/sprockets/rails/helper.rb:170:in `map'
sprockets-rails (3.4.2) lib/sprockets/rails/helper.rb:170:in `stylesheet_link_tag'
app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:10
actionview (7.0.4) lib/action_view/base.rb:244:in `public_send'
actionview (7.0.4) lib/action_view/base.rb:244:in `_run'
actionview (7.0.4) lib/action_view/template.rb:157:in `block in render'
activesupport (7.0.4) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:208:in `instrument'
actionview (7.0.4) lib/action_view/template.rb:361:in `instrument_render_template'
actionview (7.0.4) lib/action_view/template.rb:155:in `render'
actionview (7.0.4) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:76:in `block in render_with_layout'
activesupport (7.0.4) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:206:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (7.0.4) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:24:in `instrument'
activesupport (7.0.4) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:206:in `instrument'
actionview (7.0.4) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:74:in `render_with_layout'
actionview (7.0.4) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:59:in `render_template'
actionview (7.0.4) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:11:in `render'
actionview (7.0.4) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:61:in `render_template_to_object'
actionview (7.0.4) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:29:in `render_to_object'
actionview (7.0.4) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:117:in `block in _render_template'
actionview (7.0.4) lib/action_view/base.rb:270:in `in_rendering_context'
actionview (7.0.4) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:116:in `_render_template'
actionpack (7.0.4) lib/action_controller/metal/streaming.rb:216:in `_render_template'
actionview (7.0.4) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:103:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (7.0.4) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:46:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (7.0.4) lib/action_controller/metal/renderers.rb:141:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (7.0.4) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:25:in `render'
actionpack (7.0.4) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:30:in `render'
actionpack (7.0.4) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:22:in `block (2 levels) in render'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.1.2/lib/ruby/3.1.0/benchmark.rb:311:in `realtime'
activesupport (7.0.4) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:14:in `ms'
actionpack (7.0.4) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:22:in `block in render'
actionpack (7.0.4) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:91:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
activerecord (7.0.4) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:34:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
actionpack (7.0.4) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:21:in `render'
actionpack (7.0.4) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:35:in `default_render'
actionpack (7.0.4) lib/action_controller/metal/basic_implicit_render.rb:6:in `block in send_action'
<internal:kernel>:90:in `tap'
actionpack (7.0.4) lib/action_controller/metal/basic_implicit_render.rb:6:in `send_action'
actionpack (7.0.4) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:215:in `process_action'
actionpack (7.0.4) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:53:in `process_action'
actionpack (7.0.4) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:234:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (7.0.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:118:in `block in run_callbacks'
actiontext (7.0.4) lib/action_text/rendering.rb:20:in `with_renderer'
actiontext (7.0.4) lib/action_text/engine.rb:69:in `block (4 levels) in <class:Engine>'
activesupport (7.0.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:127:in `instance_exec'
activesupport (7.0.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:127:in `block in run_callbacks'
activesupport (7.0.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:138:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (7.0.4) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:233:in `process_action'
actionpack (7.0.4) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:22:in `process_action'
actionpack (7.0.4) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:67:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (7.0.4) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:206:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (7.0.4) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:24:in `instrument'
activesupport (7.0.4) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:206:in `instrument'
actionpack (7.0.4) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:66:in `process_action'
actionpack (7.0.4) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:259:in `process_action'
activerecord (7.0.4) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:27:in `process_action'
actionpack (7.0.4) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:151:in `process'
actionview (7.0.4) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:39:in `process'
actionpack (7.0.4) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:188:in `dispatch'
actionpack (7.0.4) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:251:in `dispatch'
actionpack (7.0.4) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:49:in `dispatch'
actionpack (7.0.4) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:32:in `serve'
actionpack (7.0.4) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:50:in `block in serve'
actionpack (7.0.4) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:32:in `each'
actionpack (7.0.4) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:32:in `serve'
actionpack (7.0.4) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:852:in `call'
warden (1.2.9) lib/warden/manager.rb:36:in `block in call'
warden (1.2.9) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'
warden (1.2.9) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
rack (2.2.4) lib/rack/tempfile_reaper.rb:15:in `call'
rack (2.2.4) lib/rack/etag.rb:27:in `call'
rack (2.2.4) lib/rack/conditional_get.rb:27:in `call'
rack (2.2.4) lib/rack/head.rb:12:in `call'
actionpack (7.0.4) lib/action_dispatch/http/permissions_policy.rb:38:in `call'
actionpack (7.0.4) lib/action_dispatch/http/content_security_policy.rb:36:in `call'
rack (2.2.4) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:266:in `context'
rack (2.2.4) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:260:in `call'
actionpack (7.0.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:696:in `call'
activerecord (7.0.4) lib/active_record/migration.rb:603:in `call'
actionpack (7.0.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `block in call'
activesupport (7.0.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:99:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (7.0.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:26:in `call'
actionpack (7.0.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:14:in `call'
actionpack (7.0.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/actionable_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (7.0.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:28:in `call'
web-console (4.2.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:132:in `call_app'
web-console (4.2.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:19:in `block in call'
web-console (4.2.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:17:in `catch'
web-console (4.2.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (7.0.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:26:in `call'
railties (7.0.4) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:40:in `call_app'
railties (7.0.4) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:25:in `block in call'
activesupport (7.0.4) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:99:in `block in tagged'
activesupport (7.0.4) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:37:in `tagged'
activesupport (7.0.4) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:99:in `tagged'
railties (7.0.4) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:25:in `call'
actionpack (7.0.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:93:in `call'
actionpack (7.0.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:26:in `call'
rack (2.2.4) lib/rack/method_override.rb:24:in `call'
rack (2.2.4) lib/rack/runtime.rb:22:in `call'
actionpack (7.0.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:14:in `call'
actionpack (7.0.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:23:in `call'
rack (2.2.4) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:110:in `call'
actionpack (7.0.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/host_authorization.rb:137:in `call'
railties (7.0.4) lib/rails/engine.rb:530:in `call'
puma (6.0.0) lib/puma/configuration.rb:268:in `call'
puma (6.0.0) lib/puma/request.rb:89:in `block in handle_request'
puma (6.0.0) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:343:in `with_force_shutdown'
puma (6.0.0) lib/puma/request.rb:88:in `handle_request'
puma (6.0.0) lib/puma/server.rb:430:in `process_client'
puma (6.0.0) lib/puma/server.rb:233:in `block in run'
puma (6.0.0) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:150:in `block in spawn_thread'
```

It is up and running with ruby 2.7.6 and rails 5 - I so far can't get this running with Ruby 3.0.4 or 3.1.2 (which is where I need it to be for the heroku-22 update).

Comment: Related? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49686388/upgraded-rails-4-to-rail-5-now-getting-nomethoderror-undefined-method-origin

Comment: Removing version restrictions in Gemfile: gem web-console did help. I also added gem 'sprockets-rails', :require => 'sprockets/railtie' - now the error is cleaner, but still: ActionView::Template::Error (wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 1)):

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using a very old version of `web-console` gem:

```
gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'
```

You should upgrade to a newer version, with Ruby 3 support:

```
gem 'web-console', '~> 4.2'
```

See: https://github.com/rails/web-console/blob/master/CHANGELOG.markdown

You'll probably need to add to your Gemfile the `sprockets-rails` gem, as since Rails 7 it's not a direct dependency anymore.

Comment: I took your advice here and update gem 'web-console' and added the sprockets-rails gem. Thank you for that. I have a cleaner error now, but still: ActionView::Template::Error (wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 1)): - it seems to have a problem with this line: <%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", :media => "all" %>

Comment: Actually it says: app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:8  so that is this line: <%= csrf_meta_tags %>

Answer (score 1):

I figured this out after some more playing around:

This gem 'sdoc', group: :doc gem also needed the version removed so it could update.

I ended up having a small issue with fontawesome.css not existing and the way I called to it from within bootstrap_and_overrides.css

I now have this updated to Ruby 3.1.2 - Thank you for the help Markets and Christian!

Answer (score 0):

my problem solved when i removed these gems from the gem file

```
gem 'rails-assets-sweetalert2', source: 'https://rails-assets.org'
gem 'sweet-alert2-rails'
gem 'sweet-alert-confirm'
```